# How to manage inter-dependant docker containers when moving between or cloning environments

Tags: docker, lxc

I am trying to wrap my head around how to run this particular workflow with docker.

1. Dev environment for a developer - n number of containers, like db, webserver, appserver etc with dependencies between the containers. So the database will depend only data only `volumes` container, appserver container on database and so on.
2. Now I need to port this to a new machine or environment, for e.g when a new developer joins, so that (s)he gets own environment to work with.

Step 1 is clear to me after reading [advanced docker volumes](http://crosbymichael.com/advanced-docker-volumes.html) and [tiny docker pieces](http://www.offermann.us/2013/12/tiny-docker-pieces-loosely-joined.html)

My question is related to step 2. How do I cleanly manage to reproduce this new environment with all the interdependent containers up and running properly with a (hopefully)single command?

Comment: This might be what you are looking for: https://github.com/orchardup/fig

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [fig](https://github.com/orchardup/fig) or [maestro-ng](https://github.com/signalfuse/maestro-ng).

The first one was designed for development environments, while the second one was designed for production environments; but both let you define a number of containers, with dependencies between them, and spin them up very easily from a single command.

Comment: I would say that the biggest difference is that maestro-ng has a nice lifecycle feature that can be useful if you need to check a status on the container and not that its just up. It also is multi-host. Say that you have a big database like Oracle that takes forever to load and a Weblogic that needs that datasource to work, you can create a hook in Maestro, the same is not possible with FIG AFAIK